# skip slash in string url python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using python requests to connect to a website. I am passing some strings to get data about them.

The problem is some string contains slash `/`, so when they are passed in url, I got a `ValueError`.

this is my url:

```
https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/skus/%s/listings % string
```

when string is passed (string that does not contain slash), I get:

```
https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/skus/A35-Charry-228_39/listings
```

It returns a valid response. but when i pass string which contains a slash:

```
string = "L20-ORG/BLUE-109(38)"
```

I get url like:

```
https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/skus/L20-ORG/BLUE-109(38)/listings
```

Which throws the error.

how to solve this?

Comment: what does your function look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`urllib.quote_plus` is your friend. As `urllib` is a module from the standard library, you just have to import it with `import urllib`.

If you want to be conservative, just use it with default value:

```
string = urllib.quote_plus("L20-ORG/BLUE-109(38)")
```

gives `'L20-ORG%2FBLUE-109%2838%29'`

If you know that some characters are harmless for your use case (say parentheses):

```
string = urllib.quote_plus("L20-ORG/BLUE-109(38)", '()')
```

gives `'L20-ORG%2FBLUE-109(38)'`

Comment: giving `urllib is not defined`

Comment: @ManishGupta: urllib is a module from python standard library. Just add `import urrlib` before using it. (post edited accordingly)

Comment: I did that but it didn't work. Its just encoding them but in url it doesn't matter if you use encoded chars or slash

Comment: @ManishGupta: What is the error when the url is built with `https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/skus/%s/listings % urllib.quote_plus(string)`?

Comment: I used this string : `"L20-ORG/BLUE-109(38)"`. The resulting url: `https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/skus/L20-ORG%2FBLUE-109%2838%29/listings`.  And it threw ValueError. Its because url formed is wrong.

Comment: @ManishGupta: what would be the correct URL? Can you try it directly with a browser?

Comment: No i cannot access it directly in browser. As i stated in question, When the string doesn't contain any slash, The correct url is like `https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/skus/A35-Charry-228_39/listings `. The problem is in the slash in string. Without slash, I can easily access the data.

Comment: @ManishGupta: If **you** cannot say what the correct URL should be, **I** cannot say how to build it using Python :-(

Comment: the correct url is like `https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/skus/*sku*/listings` .....that sku contains anything. In some of my cases it contains `/` that's why it is throwing error in constructing url. If this *sku* contains a slash, the url will be like: `https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/skus/<strong>some/string</strong>/listings` where "some/string" is a string with slash. if i pass something without slash, it works if present in website data.

Comment: @ManishGupta: Then the problem has nothing to do with Python. It is *how should be formatted the URL for api.flikart.net when sku contains a slash*. Only flikart.net or people knowing it can answer.

Comment: can we not do it from my side? Like make url skip the slash beforehand?

Comment: @ManishGupta: that's the question I asked you: *what do **you** want as output for input `a/b`*. **I** cannot answer that.

Answer (score 3):

Raw string literals in Python

```
string = r"L20-ORG/BLUE-109(38)"
```

You could find more info [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings) and [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#literals).

Comment: I believe you may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: Not working. It still isn't skipping the slash in url